# Can't access anymore files and applications in a Microsoft 365 account

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, microsoft365

Since a few days, I can't access my online files on OneDrive and Sharepoint. OneDrive application (on my PC) refuse to sync. In Chrome or Edge, if I try to access a file, I receive this error message:

> ***This site can’t be reached***
>
> *Check if there is a typo in XXXXXX.sharepoint.com.*
>
> - *If spelling is correct, [try running Windows Network Diagnostics](javascript:diagnoseErrors()).*
>
> *DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN*.

I tried:

- Access files on my iPhone, on my home Internet Access provider and also with my cellular network (LTE).
- Clear the cache, history, etc on my browser, close and open it
- Restart Windows
- Windows commande flushdns
- Contacted our company's IT admin and he didn't change anything about my Azure roles, licenses, etc

I can access https://www.office.com/ and I see the files I can't open.

Comment: Very wierd thing, if I start SurfShark VPN (Chrome extension) I can access my file

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!